# css vertical align middle doesn't work

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

```css
.parent{
height:50px;
background:gold;
}

.checka, .radioa, .selecta{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
<input type='checkbox' class='checka'>
<input type='radio' class='radioa'>

<select class='selecta'>
<option>lorem</option>
<option>lorem</option>
</select>
</div>
```

What is the problem with the `vertical align:middle` here? Why child element are not on middle of parent?

Comment: Because you didn't give them a height?

Comment: @j08691 we don't need height, vertical-align work with the line box (that no one can see) and not the containing block (that everyone can see) ... this will always confuse everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also add `line-height` to center them. Just make sure the `height` and `line-height` are equal. See [CSS vertical-align, how can I remove the little spacing below the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955295/css-vertical-align-how-can-i-remove-the-little-spacing-below-the-text/51955460#51955460) for another dynamic example of the effect.

```css
.parent{
height:50px;
line-height: 50px;
background:gold;
}

.checka, .radioa, .selecta{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <input type='checkbox' class='checka'>
  <input type='radio' class='radioa'>

  <select class='selecta'>
    <option>lorem</option>
    <option>lorem</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: and we still need `vertical-align:middle` ...increasing the line-height will increase the line box and keep the alignment in the middle as expected ... actually they are not exacly in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Use [flex](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/) for that is better Add the following to your parent:

```
.parent{
height:50px;
background:gold;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

and you can remove styles for : .checka, .radioa, .selecta

Comment: Does this work in IE11 too?